# How to call a funcion after success

Tags: http, go

I want to call a function (`os.Remove`) after successfully uploading a file.

I'm trying to make a one time file download endpoint which deletes the file right after it's upload.

Can I call the function just after `w.Write(data)`? What if the upload will not succeed?

My handler looks something like this:

```
func oneTimeFileDownloadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    filename, mimetype, data := getFile(r)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf(`attachment;filename="%s"`, filename))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", mimetype)
    if _, err := w.Write(data); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("error writing download data: %s", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    os.Remove(filename)
}
```

Comment: You probably want to skip `os.Remove` when encountering an error. If there is no error, the server will return the data and successful status code. There is no guarantee the client will handle it properly and the server can't know that without the client calling back after a successful download.

Comment: So if I add a return after the write error, it is ok?

Comment: Yes, if the file should **only** be deleted on successful donload. But there's still no guarantee the client correctly handled the data. And you mean "download", no "upload".

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to continue after error, so if `http.Error` does not panic your file will be deleted even if the upload fails.

To fix it you need to return form function just after calling `http.Error`.

Comment: OP changed that already. The bigger question is whether it has the intended behavior. But given the vagueness of the question, it's hard to tell.